How to use 3D human pose estimations to animate a Human Rig?
A have a sequence of JSON files with 3D coordinates for "nose", "left_eye", "right_eye", "left_ear", "right_ear", "left_shoulder", "right_shoulder", "left_elbow", "right_elbow", "left_wrist", "right_wrist", "left_hip", "right_hip", "left_knee", "right_knee", "left_ankle", "right_ankle", "forehead", "top_head" that I obtained from a 3D human pose estimation deep learning model. I assumed that I could simply enter in those coordinates to the corresponding bones of a Basic Human Metarig but it appears to only accept rotational values. Is this correct? Any suggestions on how to move forward or if there are any workarounds to input coordinate values?
